# What is the structure of the rails generate command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run the command `$ rails new foo` in the terminal my computer follows a set of instructions resulting in a bunch of folders and files being created. I, like a lot of people that are drawn to computer programming, have a desire to really understand what is happening and not just think 'Well rails is magic', so I have been searching trying to find out how this command is implemented.
I am really eager to find out what that set of instructions is and to be able to follow the process through. I have lots of books such as 'Rebuilding rails', 'The rails 4 Way' and 'Crafting rails 4 applications', but was looking for some guidance.
I have tried looking through the rails code on github and have looked through the generator files, but can't find the 'new' command.
If you could give me a guided tour of the first rails steps we know and love I would be enriched.
When I ask `$ which rails` I get `$/Users/leonormes/.rbenv/shims/rails`. When I look in that file it has:

```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
[ -n "$RBENV_DEBUG" ] && set -x

program="${0##*/}"
if [ "$program" = "ruby" ]; then
  for arg; do
    case "$arg" in
    -e* | -- ) break ;;
    */* )
      if [ -f "$arg" ]; then
        export RBENV_DIR="${arg%/*}"
        break
      fi
      ;;
    esac
  done
fi

export RBENV_ROOT="/Users/leonormes/.rbenv"
exec "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv" exec "$program" "$@"
```

which does not help me track down the `$rails new` command!
Another rails file not being used is in /.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/bin looks like;

```
    #!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'railties' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/ and Gem::Version.correct?($1) then
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

gem 'railties', version
load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails', version)
```

Comment: I am not asking for a book. I want someone to say 'look at this file here...' or 'You could start by running this command followed by --trace' or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start going through the Rails source code to understand the generators. For example, here are the usage instructions for `rails generate model`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/model/USAGE

And here is the actual generator: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/model/model_generator.rb

Interestingly, you can override any and all of these generators, which I've used to generate a lot of custom test templates off an existing schema.rb.

This [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) covers customizing generators.

Comment: Ok but the OP is asking about the rail new command, not the rails generate command. Do you know if the code for this is exposed anywhere in the API? The model_generator script is the input to the rails generate command, but what about the code for the rails generate command itself? Is that available for perusal?

Comment: Yes I mentioned generators but really I mean the rails new script. Where is it?

Answer (score 2):

I found what I was looking for. There are some dirs at `~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.beta2/lib/rails/generators/rails/app` that contain templates and such as well as a file called `app_generator.rb`. The code in this folder answers my question mostly, though I can't see how the command line `rails new` gets here. The file contains this:

```
require 'rails/generators/app_base'

module Rails
  module ActionMethods # :nodoc:
    attr_reader :options

    def initialize(generator)
      @generator = generator
      @options   = generator.options
    end

    private
      %w(template copy_file directory empty_directory inside
         empty_directory_with_keep_file create_file chmod shebang).each do |method|
        class_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
          def #{method}(*args, &block)
            @generator.send(:#{method}, *args, &block)
          end
        RUBY
      end

      # TODO: Remove once this is fully in place
      def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)
        @generator.send(meth, *args, &block)
      end
  end

  # The application builder allows you to override elements of the application
  # generator without being forced to reverse the operations of the default
  # generator.
  #
  # This allows you to override entire operations, like the creation of the
  # Gemfile, README, or JavaScript files, without needing to know exactly
  # what those operations do so you can create another template action.
  class AppBuilder
    def rakefile
      template "Rakefile"
    end

    def readme
      copy_file "README.rdoc", "README.rdoc"
    end

    def gemfile
      template "Gemfile"
    end

    def configru
      template "config.ru"
    end

    def gitignore
      template "gitignore", ".gitignore"
    end

    def app
      directory 'app'

      keep_file  'app/assets/images'
      keep_file  'app/mailers'
      keep_file  'app/models'

      keep_file  'app/controllers/concerns'
      keep_file  'app/models/concerns'
    end

    def bin
      directory "bin" do |content|
        "#{shebang}\n" + content
      end
      chmod "bin", 0755 & ~File.umask, verbose: false
    end

    def config
      empty_directory "config"

      inside "config" do
        template "routes.rb"
        template "application.rb"
        template "environment.rb"
        template "secrets.yml"

        directory "environments"
        directory "initializers"
        directory "locales"
      end
    end

    def config_when_updating
      cookie_serializer_config_exist = File.exist?('config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb')

      config

      unless cookie_serializer_config_exist
        gsub_file 'config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb', /json/, 'marshal'
      end
    end

    def database_yml
      template "config/databases/#{options[:database]}.yml", "config/database.yml"
    end

    def db
      directory "db"
    end

    def lib
      empty_directory 'lib'
      empty_directory_with_keep_file 'lib/tasks'
      empty_directory_with_keep_file 'lib/assets'
    end

    def log
      empty_directory_with_keep_file 'log'
    end

    def public_directory
      directory "public", "public", recursive: false
    end

    def test
      empty_directory_with_keep_file 'test/fixtures'
      empty_directory_with_keep_file 'test/controllers'
      empty_directory_with_keep_file 'test/mailers'
      empty_directory_with_keep_file 'test/models'
      empty_directory_with_keep_file 'test/helpers'
      empty_directory_with_keep_file 'test/integration'

      template 'test/test_helper.rb'
    end

    def tmp
      empty_directory "tmp/cache"
      empty_directory "tmp/cache/assets"
    end

    def vendor
      vendor_javascripts
      vendor_stylesheets
    end

    def vendor_javascripts
      unless options[:skip_javascript]
        empty_directory_with_keep_file 'vendor/assets/javascripts'
      end
    end

    def vendor_stylesheets
      empty_directory_with_keep_file 'vendor/assets/stylesheets'
    end
  end

  module Generators
    # We need to store the RAILS_DEV_PATH in a constant, otherwise the path
    # can change in Ruby 1.8.7 when we FileUtils.cd.
    RAILS_DEV_PATH = File.expand_path("../../../../../..", File.dirname(__FILE__))
    RESERVED_NAMES = %w[application destroy plugin runner test]

    class AppGenerator < AppBase # :nodoc:
      add_shared_options_for "application"

      # Add bin/rails options
      class_option :version, type: :boolean, aliases: "-v", group: :rails,
                             desc: "Show Rails version number and quit"

      def initialize(*args)
        super

        unless app_path
          raise Error, "Application name should be provided in arguments. For details run: rails --help"
        end

        if !options[:skip_active_record] && !DATABASES.include?(options[:database])
          raise Error, "Invalid value for --database option. Supported for preconfiguration are: #{DATABASES.join(", ")}."
        end
      end

      public_task :set_default_accessors!
      public_task :create_root

      def create_root_files
        build(:readme)
        build(:rakefile)
        build(:configru)
        build(:gitignore) unless options[:skip_git]
        build(:gemfile)   unless options[:skip_gemfile]
      end

      def create_app_files
        build(:app)
      end

      def create_bin_files
        build(:bin)
      end

      def create_config_files
        build(:config)
      end

      def update_config_files
        build(:config_when_updating)
      end
      remove_task :update_config_files

      def create_boot_file
        template "config/boot.rb"
      end

      def create_active_record_files
        return if options[:skip_active_record]
        build(:database_yml)
      end

      def create_db_files
        build(:db)
      end

      def create_lib_files
        build(:lib)
      end

      def create_log_files
        build(:log)
      end

      def create_public_files
        build(:public_directory)
      end

      def create_test_files
        build(:test) unless options[:skip_test_unit]
      end

      def create_tmp_files
        build(:tmp)
      end

      def create_vendor_files
        build(:vendor)
      end

      def delete_js_folder_skipping_javascript
        if options[:skip_javascript]
          remove_dir 'app/assets/javascripts'
        end
      end

      def delete_assets_initializer_skipping_sprockets
        if options[:skip_sprockets]
          remove_file 'config/initializers/assets.rb'
        end
      end

      def finish_template
        build(:leftovers)
      end

      public_task :apply_rails_template, :run_bundle
      public_task :generate_spring_binstubs

      def run_after_bundle_callbacks
        @after_bundle_callbacks.each do |callback|
          callback.call
        end
      end

    protected

      def self.banner
        "rails new #{self.arguments.map(&:usage).join(' ')} [options]"
      end

      # Define file as an alias to create_file for backwards compatibility.
      def file(*args, &block)
        create_file(*args, &block)
      end

      def app_name
        @app_name ||= (defined_app_const_base? ? defined_app_name : File.basename(destination_root)).tr('\\', '').tr(". ", "_")
      end

      def defined_app_name
        defined_app_const_base.underscore
      end

      def defined_app_const_base
        Rails.respond_to?(:application) && defined?(Rails::Application) &&
          Rails.application.is_a?(Rails::Application) && Rails.application.class.name.sub(/::Application$/, "")
      end

      alias :defined_app_const_base? :defined_app_const_base

      def app_const_base
        @app_const_base ||= defined_app_const_base || app_name.gsub(/\W/, '_').squeeze('_').camelize
      end
      alias :camelized :app_const_base

      def app_const
        @app_const ||= "#{app_const_base}::Application"
      end

      def valid_const?
        if app_const =~ /^\d/
          raise Error, "Invalid application name #{app_name}. Please give a name which does not start with numbers."
        elsif RESERVED_NAMES.include?(app_name)
          raise Error, "Invalid application name #{app_name}. Please give a name which does not match one of the reserved rails words."
        elsif Object.const_defined?(app_const_base)
          raise Error, "Invalid application name #{app_name}, constant #{app_const_base} is already in use. Please choose another application name."
        end
      end

      def app_secret
        SecureRandom.hex(64)
      end

      def mysql_socket
        @mysql_socket ||= [
          "/tmp/mysql.sock",                        # default
          "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock",            # debian/gentoo
          "/var/tmp/mysql.sock",                    # freebsd
          "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock",              # fedora
          "/opt/local/lib/mysql/mysql.sock",        # fedora
          "/opt/local/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock",  # mac + darwinports + mysql
          "/opt/local/var/run/mysql4/mysqld.sock",  # mac + darwinports + mysql4
          "/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock",  # mac + darwinports + mysql5
          "/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock"         # xampp for linux
        ].find { |f| File.exist?(f) } unless RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw/
      end

      def get_builder_class
        defined?(::AppBuilder) ? ::AppBuilder : Rails::AppBuilder
      end
    end

    # This class handles preparation of the arguments before the AppGenerator is
    # called. The class provides version or help information if they were
    # requested, and also constructs the railsrc file (used for extra configuration
    # options).
    #
    # This class should be called before the AppGenerator is required and started
    # since it configures and mutates ARGV correctly.
    class ARGVScrubber # :nodoc
      def initialize(argv = ARGV)
        @argv = argv
      end

      def prepare!
        handle_version_request!(@argv.first)
        handle_invalid_command!(@argv.first, @argv) do
          handle_rails_rc!(@argv.drop(1))
        end
      end

      def self.default_rc_file
        File.expand_path('~/.railsrc')
      end

      private

        def handle_version_request!(argument)
          if ['--version', '-v'].include?(argument)
            require 'rails/version'
            puts "Rails #{Rails::VERSION::STRING}"
            exit(0)
          end
        end

        def handle_invalid_command!(argument, argv)
          if argument == "new"
            yield
          else
            ['--help'] + argv.drop(1)
          end
        end

        def handle_rails_rc!(argv)
          if argv.find { |arg| arg == '--no-rc' }
            argv.reject { |arg| arg == '--no-rc' }
          else
            railsrc(argv) { |rc_argv, rc| insert_railsrc_into_argv!(rc_argv, rc) }
          end
        end

        def railsrc(argv)
          if (customrc = argv.index{ |x| x.include?("--rc=") })
            fname = File.expand_path(argv[customrc].gsub(/--rc=/, ""))
            yield(argv.take(customrc) + argv.drop(customrc + 1), fname)
          else
            yield argv, self.class.default_rc_file
          end
        end

        def read_rc_file(railsrc)
          extra_args = File.readlines(railsrc).flat_map(&:split)
          puts "Using #{extra_args.join(" ")} from #{railsrc}"
          extra_args
        end

        def insert_railsrc_into_argv!(argv, railsrc)
          return argv unless File.exist?(railsrc)
          extra_args = read_rc_file railsrc
          argv.take(1) + extra_args + argv.drop(1)
        end
    end
  end
end
```

A generator file like this executes each method in order when called. Now to read and learn!!